# Using closest('tr') without a trigger using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following code; I have a few hundred rows generated dynamically, this is just one example. I'm trying to addClass to the parent (tr) but it's not working. Any ideas?

```
<tr>
    <td style="text-align:center;">False</td>
    <td style="text-align:center;">1</td>
    <td style="text-align:center;">
    TL - Van<script>$(this).closest('tr').addClass('tl-van');</script>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: very bad habit of mixing script tag with html.

Comment: You don't have access to simply add the class on generation? Also, `this` will refer to the window object inside the script tag.

Comment: that's particular column is generated after the row is created so i have to mix which is why i'm mixing and why it can't be added prior to the row being created

Comment: How are you creating this column?  You should add the class at *that* point; in that code.  You're adding the `<td>` to the `<tr>`, so you must be able to access the element there and thus change its class.

Comment: `this` is *not* what you think it is here.  It's not the element the `<script>` tag happens to be inside of.  It's the context that the code is running in.  Since it's running outside of any context (function), then `this` is just `window` and `$(window).closest('tr')` won't find anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is coming from your misunderstanding of `this`. `this` refers to the current object/function. Using this while in the global scope refers to the window object. So, basically what you just did is..

```
<script>$(window).closest('tr').addClass('tl-van');</script>
```

.. which make no sense at all.

Use a selector, or instead of dynamically adding this script, why not just dynamically add the class in the first place..

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to apply a class to some `<tr>`, use something like the following, provided you know how to access the table.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#sometable tr").addClass('tl-van');
      // or for 4th row
      $("#sometable tr").eq(3).addClass('tl-van');
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand what you're trying to achieve with the provided code. If you want to add a class to the `<tr>` when a user clicks a button inside a child `<td>` you can try doing the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#myTable').on('click', '.btn-tl-van', function(){
            $(this).closest('tr').addClass('tl-van');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Add this snippet to the bottom of your project (before the body closing tag `</body>`). In order for this to work assign an `id="myTable"` to you `<table>` and the `class="btn-tl-val"` to your `<button>` (or other desired clickable element).

The middle argument of the `.on()` method will let jQuery look for click events in every element with the class ".btn-tl-van", even if the elements were dynamically generated.